# CheckBox selection area

Tags: asp.net, css, combobox, checkbox

I have an `<asp:ComboBox>` filled with `<asp:CheckBoxes>`. The Combobox is 200px wide. The Checkboxes are also 200px wide.

I can check the checkbox only if I click on 'box' or the checkbox text label. I want to be able to check the item even when I click anywhere on the row.

Is there any way to extend this area to the whole row?

update:
[image]

On the green area, everything is fine.
But on the red area when i click, checkbox is not checked and drop downlist goes up.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" EnableTextSelection="false" 
                     ID="rcb_Something"
                     Width="200px"
                     HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
                     AllowCustomText="true"
                     Text="Select Something"
                     MaxHeight="250px">
                     <ItemTemplate>                                                               
                          <telerik:RadBinaryImage ID="RadBinaryImage1" runat="server"
                                                  Width="24px" 
                                                  Height="24px" 
                                                  DataValue='<%# Eval("Something") %>' 
                                                  ResizeMode="Fit"  />    

                                                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"
                                                       runat="server"  
                                                       Text='<%# Eval("Something") %>' 
                                                       ToolTip='<%# Eval("SomethingId") %>'
                                                  />



                   </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: More details would help: What is the whole row that you want to be clickable?  A table row?

Comment: I updated question with code. Row is one item in combo box. It doesn't have to be whole row clickable. If I can somehow disable click on item background so that only check box can be clicked it will be enough for me. It makes me problem because when I click on item background drop down list is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Do as books say - add to every input field in HTML, a label tag with label.

```
<label for="male">Male</label> <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" />
```

Clicking anywhere on label, will activate this input, same goes for input type=text

Comment: @1110: Give the label `display: block` and `height: 100%`, so it fills the whole cell. If you need to expand the region even more, you'll need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find solution. I just disabled combobox background with following code.

JavaScript

> function StopPropagation(e) {
>               //cancel bubbling
>               e.cancelBubble = true;
>               if (e.stopPropagation) {
>                   e.stopPropagation();
>               }
>           }

aspx

```
 <div onclick="StopPropagation(event)">



<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"
              runat="server"  
              Text='<%# Eval("something") %>' 
              ToolTip='<%# Eval("somethingId") %>'
               />
</div>
```